# How to print strings that are a field in a node in a BST

Tags: c

What if one of the fields I have is a char array of size 12. How do I print out that field? I tried `%s` and `%c`, but it ends up printing garbage. I also tried a for loop, and printing out each character separately but that also did not work.

```
struct listing
{
    int id;
    char agent[12];
    int price;
    int size; //In square feet
    int numBeds;
    double numBaths;
    int yearBuilt;
    char address[ADD_LENGTH];
    struct listing *left;
    struct listing *right;
};
```

Assume that these fields have information:

```
struct listing* newNode = addListing(root, 165, "Target", 78, 50, 12, 8.0, 2017, "1648 Relish Lane");

printf("LID  Agent  Price $K  Size  Bd  Bth  Yr    Address");
printf("\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------");
printf("%d %s  %d     %d   %d  %lf  %d  %s ", node->id, node->agent, node->price, node->size, node->numBeds,
node->numBaths, node->yearBuilt, node->address);
```

This is printing out garbage

Comment: could you post your code to take a look on it?

Comment: `%.12s` will print a character array of size 12, up to the first null terminator in the array. If no null terminator is present after 12 characters, then it will also stop printing the array. However, if you used a loop to print each of the 12 characters with `%c`, and it didn't work, then you likely have a bug elsewhere (e.g. your field may be uninitialized, or something is writing garbage to it).

Comment: Use `printf("[%.12s]\n", bstnode->field);` or something similar.

Comment: I have added some code for you guys to look at

Comment: There's a very old saying in the world of computers: GIGO — Garbage In, Garbage Out.  Your code doesn't show us how `addListing()` works.  However, you assign to `newNode` and then print `node` — there's a disconnect there of some sort.  Either you weren't careful enough in your editing, or that's your problem.  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Fragments of code lead to fragments of answers.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks though everyone for your input!